# Splitting JavaScript string using an unknown length string such as \n

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a String generated from the backend with an unknown length of `\n` at different positions. Meaning I have something like:

> Lorem Ipsum\n\n\dolor sit amet\n\n\n\n\n,consecteur adipiscing\nelit

Is there a way to split this string into an array using the random length `\n` character?

Edit: Here are some extra technical details:

I'm using `Apache POI` with `JEE` to parse a word document so the string that I return as a response is generated by the library and I have no control over it. I've gone through the class used by the library and it's indeed adding `\n` characters when it finishes parsing a paragraph, it also adds a `\t` character for titles and subtitles, here is a minimized example of how the string is exactly returned:

> "I.\tIntroduction\t3\nII.\tECMA International :\t3\nIII.\tECMAScript &
>   JavaScript :\t3\nIV.\tEditions ECMAScript :\t4\nV.\tECMAScript 2015
>   :\t5\na.\tNouvelles fonctionnalités « Number » et « Math »
>   :\t5\n�?�\tEntiers Littéraux :\t5\n�?�\tNouvelles propriétés pour les
>   objets « Number » et « Math » :\t5\nb.\tNouvelles fonctionnalités pour
>   les strings :\t6\nc.\tLet &
>   Const :\t6\n�?�\tLet :\t7\n�?�\tConst :\t8\nd.\tFonctions
>   fléchées :\t8\ne.\tClasses :\t10\n�?�\tDéfinition d�??une
>   classe :\t10\n�?�\tHéritage :\t11\n�?�\tMéthodes et propriétés
>   statiques :\t12\n�?�\tGetters &
>   Setters :\t12\nf.\tModules :\t13\ng.\tParamètres par
>   défaut :\t14\nh.\tLa boucle For-Of :\t14\ni.\tGénérateurs
>   :\t15\nj.\tPromises :\t15\nVI.\tConclusion :\t18\nVII.\tBibliographie :\t19\n\n\n\n"

This represents the summary of the document (a piece of the entire string).

Passing this string directly to a split works, but passing the returned data like below doesn't:

```
ajax.post('tech/technology',`technology=${id}`)
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data.response.split(/\n+/));
})
```

Comment: Well, it works with your example, we can't see what doesn't work with the whole text if you don't show it.

Comment: @Toto The whole text is too long to paste here, the problem as I noticed isn't in the text itself. I've tried to split it directly from the response which didn't work (it logs an array with 2 values, the string itself and an empty string), however if I copy the entire string and I pass it to a variable and split it, it works. So the problem is this `data.response` is not a well formed string when parsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split on a regex of `\n+`, which will split the string at one or more `\n` characters:

```js
const str = 'Lorem Ipsum\n\n\dolor sit amet\n\n\n\n\n,consecteur adipiscing\nelit';
console.log(str.split(/\n+/));
```

Note that it may actually be more efficient to split on a single `\n` character and then filter out empty strings (thus avoiding a regex):

```js
const str = 'Lorem Ipsum\n\n\dolor sit amet\n\n\n\n\n,consecteur adipiscing\nelit';

console.log(str.split('\n').filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be working in short length strings. The string I have is quiet lengthy and this approach doesn't to work.

Comment: @Amine: How doesn't it work? How long is your string? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Toto I'm not getting any error, I'll update my original post with the code I'm using.

Comment: @Amine sorry about lack of response - been night time here, Perhaps the character isn't a newline but actually a literal backslash followed by an `n`? Can you try `str.split(/(?:\\n)+/)` to see what that does?

Comment: @Nick Yes, that was the case, the `\n` was actually a backlash followed by an `n`. I fixed it by replacing your regex with `.split(/\\n+/)`